# CDF table for exponential distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, exponential-distribution

I know there is table for standard normal distribution CDF, but i can't find a CDF table for exponential distribution, i know i can transform exponential distribution to normal one by taking the log.

Comment: The CDF for exponential distribution with rate $\lambda$ is $F(x)=1-e^{-\lambda x}$ for $x\geq0$.

Comment: but why there is no table for it like the standard normal distribution.

Comment: Then what values must be present in that table? Can't you find these values just by using the CDF (or maybe its inverse)? The CDF of standard normal distribution cannot be used like that because its definition is an integral: $\Phi(x)=\int_{-\infty}^x\phi(u)du$ where $\phi$ denotes the corresponding density. That's IMV the reason why a table is needed there. Also I don't see how you can transform exponential distribution to normal distribution by taking the log.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137059/find-distribution-and-transform-to-normal-distribution
i found this answer for transforming exp. to normal

Comment: If $X$ has exponential distribution then $\log X$ does *not* have normal distribution. Observe that $P(\ln X\leq y)=P(X\leq e^{y})=1-e^{-\lambda e^y}$.

Comment: So Ln X is its normal distribution? 
i actually don't get it the other question i shared its link he transformed the exp. distribution to normal one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know there is table for standard normal distribution CDF, but i
>   can't find a CDF table for exponential distribution

Whether a table is necessary depends on the computational abilities of the era. At one time, a table of values of $\exp x$ would have been useful, but nowadays a button on your calculator handles that. So you get $1-\exp(-\lambda x)$ by first multiplying $\lambda$ and $x$, looking up $\exp(-\lambda x)$, and then subtracting from $1$. (There was a time when multiplication would be handled with $\lambda x=\exp(\ln\lambda+\ln\lambda x)$, using a table for both $\exp$ and $\ln$!)

> i can transform exponential distribution to normal one by taking the log

If that were true, there'd be no point having a table for each distribution, since you can take the logarithm with a table or calculator. But actually, you can't make the transformation you describe. You can't connect $1-\exp(-\lambda x)$ to $\Phi(x):=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\frac{-t^2}{2}dt$ that neatly. Today, even your calculator probably doesn't have a button for $\Phi$, although you could grab a library function to do it if you were programming.

Comment: about the transformation i found this https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/137059/find-distribution-and-transform-to-normal-distribution